# Calling JAVA class member from Native C/C++ code

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm writing an OpenGL C/C++ application which i'm porting to Android through Android NDK, JNI support. I'm having difficulties executing code from JAVA callback signaled from native.

Here is the code:

```
class OpenGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView 
{
…
     public OpenGLSurfaceView(Context context, int deviceWidth, int deviceHeight) 
    {
        super(context);
        nativeObj = new NativeLib();
        mRenderer = new OpenGLRenderer(context, nativeObj, deviceWidth, deviceHeight);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
…
    private void CallBack()
    {
        // force redraw
        requestRender();
    }
}


class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{
    …
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
    {
        nativeObj.init(…);
        nativeObj.cachejavaobject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj); // for caching obj on native side
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) 
    {
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    {
        nativeObj.draw(…);
    }
}
```

And in native code i have a function texturesLoaded() that is signaled when some textures are loaded completely on another thread and i need to force a refresh from nativeLib.draw(…) on the JAVA side. Here is how i do it :

I cache the JavaVM, jClass, jMethodID on JNI_OnLoad, and gJObjectCached

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved)
{
gJVM = jvm;  // cache the JavaVM pointer

LogNativeToAndroidExt("JNILOAD!!!!!!!!!!");
JNIEnv *env;
int status = gJVM->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
if(status < 0)
{
    LogNativeToAndroidExt("Failed to get JNI environment, assuming native thread");
    status = gJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
    if(status < 0)
    {
        LogNativeToAndroidExt("callback_handler: failed to attach current thread");
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
}

gJClass = env->FindClass("com/android/newlineactivity/NewLineGLSurfaceView");
if(gJClass == NULL)
{
    LogNativeToAndroidExt("Can't find Java class.");
    return JNI_ERR;
}

gJMethodID = env->GetMethodID(gJClass, "callback", "()V");
if(gJMethodID == NULL)
{
    LogNativeToAndroidExt("Can't find Java method void callback()");
    return JNI_ERR;
}

return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
```

}

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_android_OpenGL_NativeLib_cachejavaobject(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    // cache the java object
    gJObjectCached = obj;
...
}
```

and then on texturesLoaded() i do :

```
void texturesLoaded()
{
    // Cannot share a JNIEnv between threads. You should share the JavaVM, and use JavaVM->GetEnv to discover the thread's JNIEnv
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    int status = gJVM->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if(status < 0)
    {
        LogNativeToAndroidExt("callback_handler: failed to get JNI environment, assuming native thread");
        status = gJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        if(status < 0)
        {
            LogNativeToAndroidExt("callback_handler: failed to attach current thread");
            return;
        }
    }

    LogNativeToAndroidExt("Calling JAVA method from NATIVE C/C++");
    env->CallVoidMethod(gJObjectCached, gJMethodID);
    LogNativeToAndroidExt("DONE!!!");
}
```

Result… from native side i get the class, i get the method, method gets called, but when it reaches/calls requestRender() inside(or trying to access any other member method of GLSurfaceView it crashes!)

I cannot try with CallStaticVoidMethod(gJClass, gjMethodID); because then i don't have access to requestRender();

Any ideas or opinions, maybe i'm doing something wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: `requestRender()` is in Java, so crashes usually are accompanied by an exception. Could you mention what that exception is. The Android ADB logs should reveal such information. Go [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html) to find out about logs

Answer (score 3):

You need to create *global references* to the class/object that you stash away. The references you're saving are *local references*, which can't be shared across threads and disappear when the runtime cleans up the JNI local reference stack.

Check out the [Sun/Oracle documentation for global and local references](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp16785), and check out JNI methods [`JNIEnv::NewGlobalRef`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#NewGlobalRef) and [`JNIEnv::DeleteGlobalRef`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#DeleteGlobalRef).

```c
gJClass = env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass( ... ));

gJObjectCached = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
```

*(Edit: Turns out you don't need global references for method IDs.)*

Comment: Your answer is very useful, but it doesn't help my problem. My global cached jclass and jmethodID are valid,i can reach my JAVA callback, which is a member of that class(its not static). The problem is that i cannot call another member of that class from that callback, because i think the jobject i cache doesn't point to: "com/android/newlineactivity/NewLineGLSurfaceView" because i cache it in another JENV probably. So for a static member this works : env->CallStaticVoidMethod(gJClass, gJMethodID); but for a non-static this doesn't : env->CallVoidMethod(gJObjectCached, gJMethodID);Makes sense?

Comment: Is `gJObjectCached` a global reference, or did you just store the local reference that was passed into `cachejavaobject`?

Comment: Its a global reference and is valid at the time i call env->CallVoidMethod(gJObjectCached, gJMethodID); But that callback() crashes when it calls requestRender() internally. I even tried jobject jobj = env->NewObject(gJClass, gJMethodID); and pass that, in hopes that with the correct env, gjClass and gJMethodID i can call the method and it will work... the methods gets called but crashes again at requestRender();

Comment: hmmm... your question its a bit confusing... jobject gJObjectCached; is declared global in my *.cpp file and i store in it the local reference that was passed into cachejavaobject using : JNIEXPORT void Java_com_android_OpenGL_NativeLib_cachejavaobject(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
 // cache the java object
 gJObjectCached = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
 LogNativeToAndroidExt("gjObjectCached global");
}

Comment: If you're doing `gJObjectCached = env->NewGlobalRef(obj)` then you're storing a global reference, which is what you should be doing. If things still aren't working after doing that, I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: Thank you Stuart for all your follow ups. It helped me get a view on things. I think that a solution would be to move cachejaveobject() and all my other native methods from the NativeLib into the same class : OpenGLSurfaceView. That way obj, and subsequently gJObjectCached will point to the correct location. I will update here if that works in case somebody has this problem.